# How to add minutes to string date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, time, momentjs

i have a date string from an API that looks like this **10:00** and i need add a 1 and a half, i tried with this but it doesn´t work

```js
    moment('10:00').add(90, 'minute')
```

i expect this output **11:30**

Comment: There really isn't such a thing as a date string. You have a string. You'll need to create a `Date` object from that string. Then you can modify the value of that date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let time = "10:00"

const add=(minutes)=>{
  let [hr, min] = time.split(":")
  minutes += parseInt(hr)*60 + parseInt(min)
  hr = Math.floor(minutes/60)
  min = minutes %60
  
  //console.log(hr%12+":"+ min)
  return (hr%12+":"+ min)
}

console.log(add(90))
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed the 12 to 24 in the return statement to get a 24hrs format but your solution solve the problem

Comment: Awesome, happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

See comments inline:

```js
let input = "10:00";
let inputParts = input.split(":");    // Split the string at the colon

let d = new Date();                   // Create new date
d.setUTCHours(+inputParts[0] + 1);    // Get first part of string and add 1
d.setUTCMinutes(30);                  // Adjust by 1.5 minutes

// Output in the format you want
console.log(d.getUTCHours() + ":" + d.getUTCMinutes());
```